# F test for model selection other than linear regression

Tags: model-selection, f-test

I have tried googling this, but all results lead me to F-tests for model selection specifically for linear regressions (or even other non-model selection F-tests). Maybe I'm missing the right vocabulary and/or conceptual basis for a better search.

Suppose I have a sample of $\{X_i\}_{1\leq i\leq n}$ known/assumed to be iid, and two candidate distributions:

1. $X_i\sim\mathcal{D}_1(\mathbf{\theta_1})$
2. $X_i\sim\mathcal{D}_2(\mathbf{\theta_2})$

My intuition is that one could compute $X^2_{\nu_1,1}$ and $X^2_{\nu_2,2}$ the chi-squared statistics for goodness-of-fit of the sample to models 1 and 2 respectively, and then use $F=\frac{X^2_{\nu_1,1}}{X^2_{\nu_2,2}}, F\sim F(\nu_1,\nu_2)$ as a statistic for an F-test to tell if both models are equally good/bad ($H_0$) or one is significantly better than the other (or at least, less wrong, I know [all models are wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong), but as an engineer, sometimes one just needs to pick one).

Does this make *any* sense?

Comment: There are major problems with this kind of model selection. You will inflate your sense of performance and distort your downstream inferences. [If you’ve seen the dangers of stepwise regression, this is related.](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/) What do you want to do with your model once you have selected it?

Comment: @Dave, thank you for your time. Here's the thing: in short, there's literature that says vehicular time headways distribute LN under free-flow and LL under congestion _if_ there is a steady traffic state. Now, _in the wild_ traffic states are not always steady, so it is likely that neither distribution would be an acceptable fit at times. I was wondering if one can tell that one is more likely than the other through this kind of test.

Comment: I understand that, if the 'better' distribution does not fit well, any downstream inference could be inaccurate. Rather than deciding 'model 1 is the right one' I'd like to be able to say 'model 1 is arguably better, even if not necessarily good enough'.

Comment: In other words (after having a look at the post you link), I don't really need perfect quantitative accuracy, but a qualitative sense of comparison (i.e., if a test yields a p-value of, say, 1e-10, even if it is inaccurate, I have some evidence favoring one model's superiority).